# Is Bones a vegetarian or not?

Tags: character, bones

In some episodes she is, in other ones she is eating (or trying to eat) a turkey sandwich or cooking dinner (chicken). I am confused and would like to know if this is the problem of many writers on same TV show?

Comment: Is there some rule that non vegetarian can't eat veg sandwich?

Comment: @SSimon,  a vegetarian is hard to meet his protein need; I've seen people who are actual vegetarians, but will eat meat occasionally when they need protein

Comment: @AnkitSharma it was turkey sandwish from first season, her boyfriend offered to share

Comment: @Shevliaskovic Cultural note: In the USA, a person who eats meat occasionally when they need protein would be criticized for calling themselves a vegetarian. There are plenty of ways to have a high protein diet without meat, including eggs and dairy.

Comment: It's largely a myth that it would be hard to get proteins from a vegetarian diet. If a vegetarian eats meat because of proteins, they're using it as a convenient excuse because they want to eat meat.

Comment: Bones is a rich white woman with access to high quality veggies, fruits and nuts, and supplements, and is the type of person to stick to her morals when practical (again, she's rich, so its always practical).

Comment: @Moyli It's *entirely* a myth. Getting complete protein is easy even with a vegan diet, and it's trivially easy for vegetarians who also eat eggs and dairy.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/umKXQLx.png

Comment: @Shevliaskovic - those people that you see eating meat are not actual vegetarians, they are omnivores (or a flexitarians or meat minimalists, or whatever they want to call themselves), since a vegetarian, by definition, does not eat meat. Just like  how a person that smokes a cigarette only occasionally  is not a "non-smoker".

Answer (score 18):

She wasn't a vegetarian when the show began. However, to [quote from the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperance_%22Bones%22_Brennan):

> She promised to consider becoming a vegetarian after seeing how pigs
>   were slaughtered (which was also the way her mother had been killed)
>   [*Season 1 finale - The Woman in Limbo*]. However, in "The Tough Man in the Tender
>   Chicken" (season 5, episode 6) Angela cites health reasons for
>   Brennan's vegetarian diet.

So, after Season 1 she became a vegetarian. This would also suit Emily Deschanel, [who is a vegan](http://www.vegetariantimes.com/article/one-on-one-with-emily-deschanel/).

However, despite being a vegetarian, it doesn't mean she won't cook meat for *other* people (many vegetarians do).

Comment: It's also not uncommon for people to eat vegetarian meals most of the time, [but occasionally eat meat](http://www.webmd.com/diet/can-you-be-vegetarian-still-eat-meat) (such people may identify as a "sometimes vegetarian" or "flexitarian"). I personally know people who eat meat about once a month yet still identify as vegetarian since the rest of their meals are 100% vegetarian.

Comment: @Thunderforge around here those people are called hipsters.